# window.getMatchedCSSRules for all rules including its pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, chromium-embedded

I am trying to get matched CSS rules of an element, using chrome's `window.getMatchedCSSRules` method. But this method does not gives me rules of its pseudo elements and pseudo classes. But by passing pseudo class/element name as the second argument to the method, individually it returns rules.

```
window.getMatchedCSSRules(btn, "before")
window.getMatchedCSSRules(btn, "after")
window.getMatchedCSSRules( progressEle, "-webkit-progress-value")
```

But is there a way to get all css rules including all of its pseudo class/element rules, without passing a particular pseudo element/class name as argument?

Comment: I haven't seen this before. It appears that the method was never intended for use in web sites; it was an internal method meant for use by dev tools only, and it has been deprecated even there. Explains why I can't find any documentation for it anywhere.

Comment: Yes @BoltClock its not intended for websites. I am using this for my desktop application which is based on [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) which is having all chrome APIs

Comment: IIRC, this method was originally implemented in WebKit specifically for the purpose of Web Inspector (from which Chrome DevTools grew afterwards,) as it used JavaScript APIs to access the page information (including CSS) initially. There is a [Remove getMatchedCSSRules](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79653) issue in the WebKit bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't target pseudo elements with javascript or jquery as they are not (yet) dom elements.

However, if you want to manipulate css elements through js - you might be able to achieve a similar effect with https://github.com/Box9/jss

Hope that helps